# CAS 4.0 Services Management Web Application - Application Not Authorized to Use CAS

Tags: php, codeigniter, cas

can anyone help me coz i really don't understand with CAS (newbie).
I have url `http://localhost/program/phpcas/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/` , if there's anyone access that url should redirect/using SSO CAS in `http://localhost:8080/cas`.

But i have a trouble, if i access `http://localhost/program/phpcas/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/` i got a message error from cas :

> **Application Not Authorized to Use CAS**
>
> The application you attempted to authenticate to is not authorized to use CAS.

Here's CAS code :

**ServiceManagementWebApplication-52497044623301.json**

```
{
  "@class" : "org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^http://localhost/program/phpcas/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/",
  "name" : "Services Management Web Application",
  "id" : 52497044623301,
  "description" : "Services Management Web Application",
}
```

**propertyFileConfigurer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <description>
        This file lets CAS know where you've stored the cas.properties file which details some of the configuration
        options
        that are specific to your environment. You can specify the location of the file here. You may wish to place the
        file outside
        of the Servlet context if you have options that are specific to a tier (i.e. test vs. production) so that the
        WAR file
        can be moved between tiers without modification.
    </description>

    <util:properties id="casProperties" location="${cas.properties.config.location:/WEB-INF/cas.properties}"/>

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="casProperties"/>

</beans>
```

Here's PHPCAS using CI3 for this url :

**config/cas.php**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['cas_server_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/cas';
$config['phpcas_path'] = 'application/libraries/phpcas/source';
$config['cas_disable_server_validation'] = TRUE;
```

**libraries/cas.php**

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function cas_show_config_error(){
    show_error("CAS authentication is not properly configured.<br /><br />
    Please, check your configuration for the following file:
    <code>config/cas.php</code>
    The minimum configuration requires:
    <ul>
       <li><em>cas_server_url</em>: the <strong>URL</strong> of your CAS server</li>
       <li><em>phpcas_path</em>: path to a installation of
           <a href=\"https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS\">phpCAS library</a></li>
        <li>and one of <em>cas_disable_server_validation</em> and <em>cas_ca_cert_file</em>.</li>
    </ul>
    ");
}
class Cas {
    public function __construct(){
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
            show_error('<strong>ERROR:</strong> You need to install the PHP module
                <strong><a href="http://php.net/curl">curl</a></strong> to be able
                to use CAS authentication.');
        }
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI = $CI;
        $CI->config->load('cas');
        $this->phpcas_path = $CI->config->item('phpcas_path');
        $this->cas_server_url = $CI->config->item('cas_server_url');
        if (empty($this->phpcas_path) 
            or filter_var($this->cas_server_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
            cas_show_config_error();
        }
        $cas_lib_file = $this->phpcas_path . '/CAS.php';
        if (!file_exists($cas_lib_file)){
            show_error("<strong>ERROR:</strong> Could not find a file <em>CAS.php</em> in directory
                <strong>$this->phpcas_path</strong><br /><br />
                Please, check your config file <strong>config/cas.php</strong> and make sure the
                configuration <em>phpcas_path</em> is a valid phpCAS installation.");
        }
        require_once $cas_lib_file;
        if ($CI->config->item('cas_debug')) {
            phpCAS::setDebug();
        }
        // init CAS client
        $defaults = array('path' => '', 'port' => 443);
        $cas_url = array_merge($defaults, parse_url($this->cas_server_url));
        phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, $cas_url['host'],
            $cas_url['port'], $cas_url['path']);
        // configures SSL behavior
        if ($CI->config->item('cas_disable_server_validation')){
            phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
        } else {
            $ca_cert_file = $CI->config->item('cas_server_ca_cert');
            if (empty($ca_cert_file)) {
                cas_show_config_error();
            }
            phpCAS::setCasServerCACert($ca_cert_file);
        }
    }
    /**
      * Trigger CAS authentication if user is not yet authenticated.
      */
    public function force_auth()
    {
        phpCAS::forceAuthentication();
    }
    /**
     *  Return 
     */
    public function user()
    {
        if (phpCAS::isAuthenticated()) {
            $userlogin = phpCAS::getUser();
            $attributes = phpCAS::getAttributes();
            return (object) array('userlogin' => $userlogin,
                'attributes' => $attributes);
        } else {
            show_error("User was not authenticated yet.");
        }
    }
    /**
     *  Logout and redirect to the main site URL,
     *  or to the URL passed as argument
     */
    public function logout($url = '')
    {
        if (empty($url)) {
            $this->CI->load->helper('url');
            $url = base_url();
        }
        phpCAS::logoutWithRedirectService($url);
    }
    public function is_authenticated()
    {
        return phpCAS::isAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('cas');
    $this->cas->force_auth();
    $user = $this->cas->user();
    echo "<h1>Hello, $user->userlogin!</h1>";
}
```

Please, if you know how to fix it can you tell me ?

Comment: I use the cas overlay template. I didnt find a file propertyFileConfigurer.xml

Answer (score 0):

If your are using CAS 4.0.x, you must authorize your service in deployerConfigContext.xml . 
It's found in src/main/webapp/WEBINF/ . 
In the file you'll find multiple default configurations. For demo purposes, use cas in open mode `serviceId="^(https?|imaps?)://.*` (not recommanded).